# Preferred way to write a WSGI middleware for Flask

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

I would like to write a WSGI middleware that will work with my flask application. Any examples on how I can do that ? I found one on their documentation, but it says that it is not the preferred way to do it, so wondering what is ?

I would like to write a function which encrypts the session information and sends it as a cookie on response. On request it decrypts the cookie, and passes it forward as a hash. Basically client side session management as an encrypted cookie.

Comment: What kind of WSGI middleware are you talking about? Don't forget that Flask is itself based of Werkzeug.

Comment: I have made the edit to reflect that, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em.. have you read the Flask or Werkzeug docs? Flask allows passing cryptographycally **signed** [session](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#sessions) data via cookies. If you want some secure cookie-based session management of your own, check the [SecureCookieSessionInterface](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.sessions.SecureCookieSessionInterface).